# Singleton Vs Singleton Factory

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

We have a system which has a lot of model objects (e.g. `Car`, `Pedestrian`, `Road`, ...)

Currently all of them have managers (`CarManager`, `PedestrianManager`, `RoadManager`) that return a singleton of the respective class.

An alternative  proposed is to have a `ManagerFactory` singleton that can return instances of `CarManager`, `PedestrianManager`, `RoadManager`. (e.g. `ManagerFactory.getInstance().getCarManager()`)

We also write test for the project and the concern was that if we will use Dependency Injection we will need an actual instance of an object to inject managers.

Is this alternative a good one? Would you change the singleton into something else in this case?

Comment: This is opinion, but I'd go for whatever option give you the least amount of coupling/cross-dependencies between different parts of your code. And also whatever requires you to distribute knowledge of how your code works across your codebase, if that makes sense.

Comment: My instinct however is to not have `ManagerFactory`--I think that's less complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A singleton directly or a singleton factory are basically the same thing - an opaque reference to something - a hidden dependency. With a global text search you can find these dependencies so neither option makes the situation better or worse.

Dependency injection means that you're publicly declaring that for instance A to work it needs an instance of B (or an instance which conforms to protocol C is a better dependency situation). This requires that you instantiate B somewhere and pass it to A.

From a test point of view dependency injection is far superior, because you generally want to create a mock version of B and use that to test A. The test injects the instance to use. Testing singletons is a pain...

So, ideally, the first class involved would create an instance of B and pass it to the other classes that need it, and that instance gets passed on from there.

Comment: So overall what you are saying is that the two approaches are the same thing but the second one is better since it allows for Dependency Injection?

Comment: Singletons don't prevent dependency injection as such, but if you're using dependency injection you wouldn't usually use a singleton. For the factory, use it if it adds some value, if it's literally just calling alloc+init then it adds no value, if it has some builder logic then it may add value.